# Show that $504 \mid (n^9 − n^3 )$ for any integer $n$

Tags: number-theory

Not sure what to do / how to start this... I have equcation of 504 is: $2 \cdot2 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 7$

Comment: Hint: $n^3$ is either $0$ or $1$ mod $8$, and either $-1,0$ or $1$ mod $9$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that 504 | (n^9 − n^3 ) for any integer n](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1630704/show-that-504-n9-%e2%88%92-n3-for-any-integer-n)

Comment: Oh, I see the other question was migrated from another SE site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $504 = 2^3\cdot3^2\cdot7$ and 
$n^9-n^3=n^3(n^6-1)=n^3(n^2-1)(n^4+n^2+1)$.

Then:

- For $m=2^3$, we have $n^2-1 \equiv 0$ for $n$ odd and $n^3 \equiv 0$ for $n$ even.
- For $m=3^2$, we have $\phi(m)=6$ and so $n^6-1 \equiv 0$ when $n$ is not a multiple of $3$ and $n^3 \equiv 0$ when $n$ is a multiple of $3$.
- For $m=7$, we have $\phi(m)=6$ and so $n^6-1 \equiv 0$ when $n$ is not a multiple of $7$ and $n^3 \equiv 0$ when $n$ is a multiple of $7$.

The last two come from Fermat's theorem.

Comment: The decomposition of the polynomial is incorrect. The RHS has a nonzero first-degree term $n.$

Comment: @Justpassingby, fixed, thanks.

Comment: In the first line you have 6 instead of 7

Answer (score 3):

Hint: decompose the polynomial $n^9-n^3$ into linear and quadratic irreducible factors. Observe divisibility for $2^3,$ $3^2$ and $7$ separately.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{n^9-n^3}{504}\\
&=\small720\binom{n}{9}+2880\binom{n}{8}+4620\binom{n}{7}+3780\binom{n}{6}+1655\binom{n}{5}+370\binom{n}{4}+36\binom{n}{3}+\binom{n}{2}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: +1 It's often easier, for odd polynomials, to use the odd polynomials $\binom{n+k}{2k+1}$ as your basis, but I still love this kind of answer. (Keeping the basis odd means fewer terms.)

Comment: The "odd" formula is: $$\frac{n^9-n^3}{504}=720\binom{n+4}{9}+300\binom{n+3}{7}+35\binom{n+2}{5}+{{n+1}\choose{3}}$$