# Prove that $6$ divides $n^3+11n$?

Tags: divisibility

How can i show that
$$6\mid (n^3+11n)$$

My thoughts:
I show that
$$2\mid (n^3+11n)$$
$$3\mid (n^3+11n)$$

And
$$n^3+11n=n\cdot (n^2+11)$$
And if $n=x\cdot 3$ for all $x \in \mathbb{N}$ then:
$$3\mid (n^3+11n)$$
And if not:

The cross sum of$$n^2+11$$
is multiple of 3.

Can this be right or is there a simple trick?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

$$n^3+11n=\underbrace{(n-1)n(n+1)}_{\text{Product of three consecutive integers}}+12n$$

See [The product of n consecutive integers is divisible by n factorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12065/the-product-of-n-consecutive-integers-is-divisible-by-n-factorial)

OR [The product of n consecutive integers is divisible by n! (without using the properties of binomial coefficients)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12067/the-product-of-n-consecutive-integers-is-divisible-by-n-without-using-the-prop)

Answer (score 5):

It is easier to understand the part for factor $3$ to check if $n^3+11n = 0 \pmod 3$.

Then either $n = 0 \pmod 3$ or $n = \pm 1 \pmod 3$.

The $n^2 + 11$ is then $0 \pmod 3$.

Comment: Nice approach +1

Answer (score 3):

You can also prove this by induction.

$$(n+1)^3+11(n+1)=(n^3+11n) + 3n(n+1)$$

$6$ divides the first part by induction hypothesis. Then $3$ divides $3$ and $2$ divides $n(n+1)$ (either $n$ or $n+1$ is even) so $6$ divides $3n(n+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
n^3+11n
= 12 \binom{n}{1} + 6 \binom{n}{2} + 6 \binom{n}{3}
= 6\left(2 \binom{n}{1} + \binom{n}{2} + \binom{n}{3}\right)
$$

This is obtained by using repeated differences and [Newton's interpolation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_series#Newton.27s_series):
$$
\begin{array}{llll}
0 & 12 & 30 & 60 & 108 & \\
12 & 18 & 30 & 48 & \\
6 & 12 & 18 & \\
6 & 6 & \\
0 & \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: This technique [seems to](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1673032/589) be a @robjohn favorite.

Answer (score 1):

**By brute force**:

$$(n^3+11n)\bmod6\equiv(n\bmod6)^3+11(n\bmod6)\mod6$$ and you can proceed by trying the integers $0$ to $5$.

Mentally,
$$0,12,30,60,108,180.$$

You can speed-up the computation by dropping any multiple of $6$ you meet and by using $-n$ instead of $+11n$.

---

**Incrementally**:

Compute the delta between two consecutive terms

$$(n+1)^3+11(n+1)-n^3-11n=3n(n+1)+12.$$

As one of $n$ and $n+1$ is certainly even, the delta is divisible by $6$.

The property holds for all $n$, as $0^3+11\cdot0$ is divisible by $6$.

Answer (score 1):

$$(n+1)(n+2)(n+3) = n^3 + 6n^2 + 11n + 6.$$

Comment: (Essentially the same as lab bhattacharjee's answer.)

Comment: It may be essentially the same, but +1 -- because it comes more naturally looking at the given expression.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a proof by induction,

1. setting $n=1$, one should get 
   $$n^3+11n=1^3+11\cdot 1=12$$
   obviously, the above number $12$ is divisible by $6$ hence statement is true for $n=1$.
2. Assume that the number $n^3+11n$ is divisible by $6$ for $n=k$ then 
   $$k^3+11k=6\lambda$$or $$k^3=6\lambda-11k\tag 1$$
3. Now, setting $n=k+1$, $$(k+1)^3+11(k+1)$$$$=k^3+3k^2+14k+12$$
   $$=6\lambda-11k+3k^2+14k+12$$
   $$=6\lambda+3(k^2+k+4)$$
   since, $k^2+k+4$ is even for all integer $k$ hence setting $k^2+k+4=2m$, 
   $$=6\lambda+3(2m)$$
   $$=6(\lambda+m)$$
   since, $(\lambda +m)$ is an integer hence, the above number $6(\lambda+m)$ is divisible by $6$

Hence, $n^3+11n$ is divisible by $6$ for all integers $n\ge 1$

Comment: OP was asking for a simple trick.

Answer (score -1):

using mathematical induction

crucial step is $$p(n)\Rightarrow p(n+1)$$

Let $$p(n)=n^3+11n=6k$$ then
$$p(n+1)=(n+1)^3+11(n+1)=n^3+3n^2+3n+1+11n+11=$$
$$=6k+3n^2+3n+12=6k+6(\frac{n^2+n}{2}+2)=6(k+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+2)$$

Comment: I ask downvoter what is wrong with my answer!